# Ubuntu 12.4.2 apt-get update pausing at 'Waiting for headers'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm not really sure what is going on, this is a fresh install and it happening on more than one box.

I have tried to use different sources, with no luck, my repos were pointing to us.archive.ubuntu.com and I have switched them to ca.archive.ubuntu.com with same results.

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a proxy authentication issue?

Comment: I'm not suing a proxy here! thats the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, it turned to be my firewall, I rebooted it and it start working again.

Thanks